# Installing plugins for QGIS 2.18 on mac

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis-2.18

I can't install any plugins on QGIS since updating to 2.18 (I am running High Sierra). I am connected to the QGIS Plugin Repository yet receive the error message:

> Plugin installation failed:Failed to unzip the plugin package.
>   Probably it's broken or missing from the repository. You may also want
>   to make sure that you have write permission to the plugin directory.

I have downloaded the plugin (openlayers) and extracted to the **.qgis2/python/plugins/ directory** but receive the error message: No QGIS plugins found. I am not using a proxy so don't think that is the error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i had this same error last night; i tried again just now and it worked.. Suspect it may have been a brief outage of the plugins site. Does it work if you try again?

Comment: @StevenKay - You should post your _comment_ as an **answer** :)